# Why do I need an extra cast when using the conditional operator?

Tags: c#, casting, conditional-operator

In C# I can assign a number (up to 255) directly to a variable of type byte:

```
byte red = 255;
```

However if I do this in a more complex statement with a conditional operator:

```
byte red = (redNode != null) ? byte.Parse(redNode.Value) : 255;
```

I get an error: "CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)".

I need to explicitly do the cast to byte for the 255:

```
byte red = (redNode != null) ? byte.Parse(redNode.Value) : (byte)255;
```

Why is this cast needed?

Comment: because both if else should return same type of instance

Comment: There is no implicit cast from int to byte, but there is an explicit one. It is named "explicit" for a reason - you need to apply it, well, explicitly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numeric literals in C# are `int`, not `byte`. Try `0xff`.

There is [no implicit conversion from int to byte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx), and the very first statement `byte red = 255;` is a special case.

> A constant expression of type int can be converted to sbyte, byte,
>   short, ushort, uint, or ulong, provided the value of the constant
>   expression is within the range of the destination type.

That doesn't explain why it doesn't convert the constant 255 in the second expression, does it?

It doesn't need to convert 255 in the second expression, because [there is an implicit conversion from byte to int](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx). So `byte.Parse(redNode.Value)` is converted to `int`. And so `(redNode != null) ? byte.Parse(redNode.Value) : 255;` is of type `int` - and because it's not a constant expression, there is no implicit conversion to `byte` anymore.

You think the error message asks you to do this:

```
byte red = (redNode != null) ? byte.Parse(redNode.Value) : (byte)255;
```

but it really was asking you to do that:

```
byte red = (byte)((redNode != null) ? byte.Parse(redNode.Value) : 255);
```

Comment: The point of the question is why it doesn't work in this case but does when doing a direct assignment.

Comment: But why is it different from the first assignment?

Comment: @stefan.s웃 extended the answer a bit.